# Get code outside quotes with regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, quotes

Is there a way to get a piece of code that is not between quotes (single or double) in javascript with regular expressions?

if i have this string:

```
'this is a test "this shouldn't be taken"'
```

the result should be:

```
'this is a test'
```

Comment: Your string is not valid, because of the quote at "shouldn't"

Comment: The result should be 'this is a test ' with a space at the end, shouldn't it?

Comment: I would guess, however it also says not between single or double quotes, but the solution is enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This should remove anything between single or double quotes, it works with multi-line strings (strings that contain \n or \r) and it should also handle escaped quotes:

```
var removeQuotes = /(['"])(?:\\?[\s\S])*?\1/g;

var test = 'this is a test "this shouldn\'t be taken"';
test.replace(removeQuotes, ""); // 'this is a test '

test = 'this is a test "this sho\\"uldn\'t be taken"';
test.replace(removeQuotes, ""); // 'this is a test '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myString.replace(/".*?"/g, '')
```

will remove any string between double-quotes from myString. It doesn't handle escaped double-quotes, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the quoted part of your string with the javascript [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function:

```
str = 'this is a test "this shouldn\'t be taken"';
str_without_quotes = str.replace(/(['"]).*?\1/g, "") // => 'this is a test '
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it doesn't work if there is a line break in the string.